# How do I print multiple DOCX files alphabetically?

Tags: windows, printing, docx

I have a ZIP file that my PHP web application outputs.  It contains merged DOCX files with user names for printing.  The file structure is just like this:

```
Adam Gray.docx
Amanda Black.docx
Benjamin Franklin.docx
Zane.docx
```

When we select all the files in Windows explorer and click the print button, the print spooler doesn't care about order and wants to spit them out as fast as possible.

Any way to make them spool up alphabetically?  This is needed because they have corresponding envelopes that need to be printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this exact need of yours in around 2007 to 2008. The only way I was able to get the files to be printed in order was to use a program. I just looked up that program again, installed it, and used it and it does print the files in order.

The program is called Print Conductor, which you may find here: http://www.print-conductor.com/ Once there, click on the download tab at the top and then on the link below. The program is 100% free.

Once you have installed the program, open it, drag the files you wish to print into it, click on the file name header to get them sorted in order, and then click the Start button in the bottom right.

That's it!

Have fun with it.

Comment: Works **PERFECTLY**.  Also, it is really cool that you can run more than one instance of the application to print to different printers.  You are a lifesaver @rolo